# ngOnChanges is not being called

Tags: angular, typescript

I am updating a component property, but ngOnChanges is not being called.  Please see the linked StackBlitz to see the problem reproduced and everything I have tried so far:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-becgjq

Edit: correct link to view code

Relevant code

```
ngOnInit() {
    const testButton1 = document.getElementById('test-button1');
    testButton1.addEventListener('click', function() {
      console.log('about to set this.value');
      console.log(this.value);
      this.value = 'value set by button 1';
    }.bind(this));
    const testButton2 = document.getElementById('test-button2');
    testButton2.addEventListener('click', this.testButtonCallback2(this), false);
    const testButton3 = document.getElementById('test-button3');
    testButton3.addEventListener('click', this.testButtonCallback3.bind(this), false);
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log('ngOnChanges was called');
  }

  testButtonCallback2(outerThis) {
    return function() {
      console.log('about to set this.value');
      console.log(outerThis.value);
      outerThis.value = 'value is set by callback2';
    }
  }

  testButtonCallback3() {
    console.log('about to set this.value');
    console.log(this.value);
    this.value = 'value is set by callback3';
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
```

Comment: We can't see your code with the link you posted. Post the relevant code in the question itself. And post a link to the stackblitz editor, where we can see the code.

Comment: Link edited, thank you

Comment: ngOnChanges is called when at least one **input** passed by a **parent component** is modified (i.e. when the reference to the object passed as input is changed, not when its state is modified). You have no parent component and no input here.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood the usage of the OnChanges interface.  Do you know what I'm looking for?

Comment: That's what you should tell us.

Comment: I'm trying to fire off a function when the change detector detects changes to a data-bound component property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the official [docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#onchanges).

> Angular calls its ngOnChanges() method whenever it detects changes to
>   input properties of the component (or directive).

You don't have any [inputs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#inputs-outputs) in your component so `ngOnChanges` will never be called.

Also, you should actually use the methods Angular provides. I can only recommend you to follow the [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial). For example, you should not add event listeners with `addEventListener` but with `(click)` in your template like this:

```
<button (click)="testButtonCallback()">Test Button</button>
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: My real life implementation is a callback function.  I used it with the button just to make a simple reproduction.  I referenced this official doc page https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges "A lifecycle hook that is called when any data-bound property of a directive changes. Define an ngOnChanges() method to handle the changes."  Makes it sound like it's called when any property changes

Comment: "Data-bound" is the key there.  It doesn't apply to all properties.

Comment: Basically, it applies to properties with the `@Input()` decorator. Only when the parent component changes the input, ngOnChanges will run in the child component.